# L-value required in c++

Tags: c++

I am getting an lvalue required error at ob1.name and ob2.name. Please
        help me figure it  out.

```
 #include<iostream.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 class student
 {
 public:
   int rollno;
   char name[10];
 };

 void main()
 {
   student ob1;
   student ob2;
   ob1.rollno=101;
   ob1.name="ajay"; // this is where i am getting the error
   ob2.rollno=102;
   ob2.name="pintu"; // this is where i am getting the error
   clrscr();
   cout<<"roll no and name of first student"<<ob1.rollno<<ob1.name;
   cout<<"roll no and name of second student"<<ob2.rollno<<ob2.name;
   getch();
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using `void main`

Comment: You can not assign to an array, only copy to it. Perhaps you should learn about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? Or at the very least [`std::strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcpy`

i.e.

```
strcpy(ob1.name, "ajay");
```

But a better solution would be to use `std::string`